# Uploading ".xlsx" file using DropBox API making file corrupted

Tags: c#, winforms, dropbox

```
DropboxClient dbx = new DropboxClient("************************");
var file = "/Excel/FileName.xlsx";
byte[] bytes = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
long numBytes = fs.Length;
bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bytes.ToString()));
var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(file, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: mem);
```

Here is the code, it overwrite the existing file as per need but make that file corrupted.

Comment: Could you debug and show us the original byte length, byte length in `numBytes` and when you cast `numBytes` into an int. I think the length is far too big for an int and therefore reads the incorrect amount of bytes into the byte array from the BinaryReader.

Comment: You should probably include the tag related to language used.

Comment: bytes {byte[344669]} byte[]
Here is the length of byte array .

Comment: How can you even consider converting a _binary_ XLSX file (i.e. a ZIP) into an UTF-8 string and expect it to be _not_ corrupted?

Comment: Have you even made a single attempt at debugging the problem yourself, before posting here? Calling `ToString()` on a byte array gives you the string `"System.Byte[]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're thinking too complex here. `UploadAsync` expects a `Stream`. `MemoryStream` is indeed a `Stream`, but so is `FileStream`. Getting rid of the extra reader will result in:

```
var source = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Test.xlsx";
var target = "/Excel/FileName.xlsx";

using(var dbx = new DropboxClient("***"))
using(var fs = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
        target, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: fs);
}
```

The reason the file will get corrupt is because of reading the data incorrectly. `bytes.ToString()` will result in `System.Byte[]`. You're actually uploading `System.Byte[]` literally instead of the file's contents, which is not a valid Excel document. Also converting a binary file into UTF-8 text doesn't work as expected, because it alters the content being uploaded.